# Microsoft Ribbon: Define RibbonGroupSizeDefinitions for undefined number of buttons

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribbon

I use the Microsoft Ribbons with .Net Framework 4.5 and I bind some favorites to the Ribbonbar.
My code for this is this:

```
            <RibbonGroup Header="Favorites" ItemsSource="{Binding FavoriteButtons}" >
                <RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions>
                    <RibbonGroupSizeDefinition IsCollapsed="False"/>
                </RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions>
                <RibbonGroup.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RibbonButton
                            Label="{Binding FavItem.Host}"
                            SmallImageSource="{Binding FavIconSmall}"
                            LargeImageSource="{Binding FavIconLarge}">
                        </RibbonButton>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </RibbonGroup.ItemTemplate>
            </RibbonGroup>
```

The binding works like I expect, but the `RibbonControlSizeDefinition` cannot be set by using i.e. this:

```
                <RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions>
                    <RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
                        <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="True"/>
                        <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="True"/>
                    </RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
                    <RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
                        <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="True"/>
                        <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="True"/>
                    </RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
                    <RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
                        <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="False"/>
                        <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="False"/>
                    </RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
                    <RibbonGroupSizeDefinition IsCollapsed="False"/>
                </RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions>
```

because, in each `<RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>` I have to define the number of elements, that will be shown in the `RibbonGroup`. Because of the binding, I don't know how many elements this will be.
I can add this to the `RibbonButton` in the ItemTemplate

```
<RibbonButton.ControlSizeDefinition>
    <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="True"/>
</RibbonButton.ControlSizeDefinition>
```

but the buttons will always stay large. I cannot add more than one `<RibbonControlSizeDefinition .../>` in the `<RibbonButton.ControlSizeDefinition>` like I can do this in the `<RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions>`.

How can I add `ControlSizeDefinition` to a `RibbonGroup` that is filled with elements by using a binding?

Comment: My current work-around is, to add the RibbonControlSizeDefinition a number of times, that is a number, that is something like a maximum. WPF/Ribbon doesn't seem to have a problem, if the SizeDefinition is more often declared, that buttons/controls in a group exists. Not a clean solution, but for now it works.